# Mixed effect linear model R

Tags: mixed-model, interpretation, biostatistics

Could someone please help me with interpretation of the results I've got using nlme package from R. I have 3 groups of animals, each group is divided into 3 subgroups, and each subgroup has a number of animals that are different between the subgroups. Therefore, my model is:

```
model = lme(Weight ~ Pressure + Temperature + ExperimentDuration +
            GroupSize + Food + Visits, random = ~1|Group/Subgroup/ID)
```

And the output is:

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: NULL 
   AIC     BIC    logLik
 34790.16 34853.5 -17384.08

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | Group
    (Intercept)
StdDev:    34.35705

 Formula: ~1 | Subgroup %in% Group
    (Intercept)
     StdDev:    226.1137

 Formula: ~1 | ID %in% Subgroup %in% Group
    (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    373.0889 129.1023

Fixed effects: Weight ~ Pressure + Temperature + ExperimentDuration + GroupSize +      Food + Visits 
                  Value Std.Error   DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)        4146.691 1185.6404 2330  3.497427  0.0005
Pressure             20.885    0.8103 2330 25.773011  0.0000
Temperature          -0.755    0.1564 2330 -4.830731  0.0000
ExperimentDuration  -76.050   40.7609    8 -1.865762  0.0991
GroupSize             0.027    2.0190    8  0.013603  0.9895
Food                109.921    6.8184 2330 16.121145  0.0000
Visits              115.871   65.3632 2330  1.772720  0.0764
 Correlation: 
               (Intr) Pressr Tmprtr ExprmD GropSz Food  
Pressure           -0.129                                   
Temperature        -0.002 -0.049                            
ExperimentDuration -0.955  0.025 -0.007                     
GroupSize          -0.414  0.000 -0.006  0.161              
Food               -0.128  0.795  0.047  0.032  0.005       
Visits             -0.084  0.076  0.012  0.016  0.016 -0.085

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
    Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-1.35499117 -0.22141876  0.02054664  0.22460935  1.39137790 

Number of Observations: 2349
Number of Groups: 
                  Group         Subgroup %in% Group ID %in% Subgroup %in% Group 
                      5                          15                        2349
```

The first question: I'm a bit concerned with the high AIC value, does it mean that the model is wrong? How would it be possible to improve it?

My second question: How to interpret random effect results and is there a way to perform a variance component analysis for my random effects in R?

My third question: How do decide whether I need to add an interaction term for certain variables or not?